# Params request python querystring

Tags: python, parameters, python-requests

I need to make a request with a querystring, like this `?where[id]=CXP`, but when i define it in the requests params (`params = {'where[id]': 'CXP'}`) the request returns the internal server error `500`.

```
r = requests.get('http://myurl', params=params)
```

What is the correct whay to make this request?

Thanks.

Comment: `500` means that the server processing your requests had an internal error, just like you said. Your code is fine, the server code has an error. If it is your server code, please provide it. Also check your server's console or log for what the error is

Comment: Thank you, 
But when I make a browser request, the response is fine:

Browser request:
http://myurl?where[id]=CXP

RESPONSE:

{
  "data": {
    "services": [
      {
        "id": "CXP",
        "priority": null,
        "title": null,
        "url": null,
        "visibility": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "message": "Ok",
  "statusCode": 0,
  "timestamp": 1505826297
}

Comment: Regarding my deleted comment: Nevermind about it, `requests` should deal with any url-encoding by itself

Comment: Please post the error the server emits. It can be found either in the server's log file, or it's console, depending on what kind of webserver you run and how you run it

Comment: Thank for your help Felk...
The server emit the message below:
    data = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/delivery-mod-dealer/delivery_mod_dealer/api/service.py", line 34, in api_get_services_by_user
    data = queryFilter.translateQueryString(data, request.args)
  File "/opt/delivery-mod-dealer/delivery_mod_dealer/extensions/query_filter.py", line 13, in translateQueryString
    wField = (request.query_string.rsplit('where[',1)[1]).split(']')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range


And transforming to...where%28id%29=CXP

Comment: Please edit the error message into your question with proper, readable formatting. The `%28id%29` is just the urlencoding, you shouldn't worry about it

Answer (score 0):

it is very much possible that the server requires json formating. Even though `500` doesn't look like that, it is still worth a try.
From requests' version 2.4.2 onwards, you can simply use json as parameter. It will take care of encoding for you. All you need to do is:

```
r = requests.get('http://myurl', json=params)
```

If you are (for whatever reason) using an older version of requests, you can try following:

```
import simplejson as json
r = requests.get('http://myurl', param=json.loads(params))
```

I always recommend `simplejson` over `json` package as it is updated more frequently.

EDIT: If you want to prevent urlencoding, your only solution might be to pass a string.

```
r = requests.get('http://myurl', param='where[id]=CXP')
```

Comment: The problem is, server is replacing the "[" "]" to %28 and %29, is there a way to avoid it?

/dealer/api/service?where%28id%29=CXP

Comment: Oh, I get it now. I updated my answer to provide some insight. Sorry, that I can't be more useful.

Comment: But I was late :D

Comment: Thanks for your help, and sorry for my poor English.
Regards =)

Answer (score 0):

Friends.. I Think I solve it.

**params** allow string in the request.
So, I think it's not the best way, but i´m putting as:

r = requests.get('http://myurl', params='where[service]=CXP')

And works fine!